# GCP BigQuery Column Comments Table

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery which metadata table(Information_Schema) is having Table Name, Columns and "**Column** **Comments**"?

We have Informatica connected to GCP Big Query, in Informatica "Target Mapping" we have choose option to create a backend table and load the data, it's successful but the target table is not updated with Table Column's Comments and we didn't find an option to get the column comments using  informatica tool.
The source system 100+ tables having 200 to 400 columns, each column has column comments, but informatica tool it doesn't have a feature to get as source table columns comments (this column comments feature is not available).

Looking for a possibility way to update the Metadata GCP table for all the Tables Column's comments but not altering table with column comments.

Please let me know is there a Information_Schema's table which has the tables, columns and column comments.

thanks,
PM

Answer (score 0):

You would likely want to check out the [table_options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#table_options_view) and the [column_field_paths](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#column_field_paths_view) views.  In the linked docs they also provide sample queries.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS; helped me to get the required information.

Comment: Those are metadata and are read only.  If you wanted to update column descriptions you would either use the console, bq cli, or api to modify those values.  For example here is how you would issue a DDL statement to alter the column description https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_column_set_options_statement.

If you found this answer helpful please consider upvoting and marking the answer as correct.